# Reemplazar valores de un string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una variable

```
var fruits = "Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango";
```

Lo que necesito es que cada que encuentre una "," salte la linea con un " \n " y bueno desaparesca la "," para que quede asi :

```
Banana

Orange

Apple

Mango
```

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: (hahah @MauricioAriasOlave publicamos hasta en el mismo segundo :O)

Comment: si, me podrias ayudar con mi ejercicio si no es mucha molestia ?

Comment: Por favor, lee los enlaces provistos en nuestros comentarios. Explica mejor la pregunta, muestra lo que has intentado y que errores/problemas tienes y podremos ayudarte ...

Comment: Te recomiendo leerte este artículo: https://frontendlabs.io/2456--javascript-ejemplos-substring-split-replace-trim

Si estás en un ciclo o haciendo un curso, no intentes que lo hagan por tí, investiga e inténtalo tú mismo. Nosotros estaremos aquí cuando lo intentes y no te salga.

Comment: Te agradesco mucho por la respuesta y por la informaciòn

Comment: aprende JavaScript aquí hermano: https://www.freecodecamp.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplazamos los espacios que hay en el string y luego lo separamos por las comas

```
var array_fruits = fruits.replace(/ /g, '').split(',')
```

Después iteramos el array en el que hemos convertido el string

```
for(var i = 0; i < array_fruits.length; i++){ 
   console.log(array_fruits[i]) 
}
```

Resultado:

```
Banana
Orange
Apple
Mango
```

Comment: Está bien querer ayudar pero no es bueno contestar a las preguntas donde el OP no ha mostrado haber hecho ningún esfuerzo por encontrar una solución.

Comment: recuerden que es StackOverflow, somos ajenos a la temática que hay en grupos de facebook... Colaborando entre todos podemos empujar a todo hispanoamérica para que sea potencia en el desarrollo de software :D Un comentario con la idea sería lo ideal en estos casos, ¡éxitos bro! muchas gracias por la buena fe que tienes en ayudar a responder preguntas, lo apreciamos mucho :D

Comment: @Raúl Monge ayudanos solo contestar preguntas que [mcve] de lo contrario hay que esperar